# How to use criteria based on a set of numbers with SUMIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have table like this

```
A | B | C | Val
5 | 5 | 5 | 10
5 | 4 | 5 | 20
4 | 4 | 4 | 5
3 | 3 | 4 | 7
```

Is there any way `sumifs` can use criteria based on a set of numbers?

E.g. I want to sum the `Val` column based on these cells:

```
A: 5
B: 4,5 -> means get 4 or 5
C: 5
```

Then the result is 10 + 20 = 30

```
A: 3,4,5
B: 3,4
C: 4
```

Then the result is 5 + 7 = 12

Comment: @Calculuswhiz nope, i just think about it, i didnt know another way beside sumifs

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, clearly specifying the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do it with `SUMIFS` as it does not let you express `OR` conditions with Array literals like in Excel.

However, Google Sheets does offer the `QUERY` function.

Assume that criteria for A is in H1:1, B is in H2:2, C is in H3:3:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select sum(D) where 
(A="&TEXTJOIN(" or A=",1,H1:1)&") and 
(B="&TEXTJOIN(" or B=",1,H2:2)&") and 
(C="&TEXTJOIN(" or C=",1,H3:3)&")")
```

This gives you a header too. To get just the sum you can `INDEX` it:

```
=INDEX(
QUERY(A:D,"select sum(D) where 
(A="&TEXTJOIN(" or A=",1,H1:1)&") and 
(B="&TEXTJOIN(" or B=",1,H2:2)&") and 
(C="&TEXTJOIN(" or C=",1,H3:3)&")")
,2)
```

With this, you don't have to worry about headers or the number of criteria.

For a way to do it without `QUERY` see @basic's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018029/4294399).

Comment: actually, what i want is a dynamic condition, i want to change the criteria on the other cell

Comment: @RHerpradiptoAdiansyah Oh, ok. I get it now. Just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `SUMPRODUCT` and `MMULT` functions to get dynamic formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
      ($D$2:$D$5)
      *MMULT(--($A$2:$A$5=$I$2:$K$2),ROW($A$1:$A$3)^0)
      *MMULT(--($B$2:$B$5=$I$3:$K$3),ROW($A$1:$A$3)^0)
      *MMULT(--($C$2:$C$5=$I$4:$K$4),ROW($A$1:$A$3)^0)
 )
```

[image]

Comment: it doesnt work for me, the result is always 0. i set the posisiton same as your ss and copy your code

Comment: @RHerpradiptoAdiansyah Can you share your gsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with relatively simple SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(... as shown here on [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xTfERpk1aPKuGALg8P8LE8Gsy03FYfaA6z8nWU0CpBo/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E4:E,MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B4:D),B2:D2)),SEQUENCE(3,1,1,0))=3)
```

Note the use of the number 3 in two places which is indicative of how wide your data range is. It can be made dynamic, but it's easier to see how the formula works with the 3s as "hard" numbers for now.